# Regex: Find int and long only (ignore digits in float format)

Tags: regex

I have a regex which can identify most of the int and longs in C#/C++/Java...
The regex:

```
((?<=\W)(-?\d+[lL]?)(?=\W))
```

Int and long that it can identified correctly:

```
int: 1,23,-1,-100,[13]
long: 1L,23l,23L,-1l,-100L,[16L]
if(m_ned==0) m_ned=1;
```

But I just find that it identify digital numbers in float and science format as well:

```
//NOT int and long:
not long: 1ll,1LL,1l0,1L0
not int or long: 3., .4, 5.6,
if(m_ned3==ned2) 
    m_ned=1e-7;
```

3,4,5,6,7 in the above text will be identified as int as well. Need something like "\W but not . or e". Anyone helps me out? thanks :)

Here is the sandbox for it:

https://regex101.com/r/vvGJSs/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example data, you could exclude the allowed characters on the left and the right using negative lookarounds, and use a word boundary to prevent a partial word match.

```
(?<![\w.-])-?\d+[lL]?\b(?!\.)
```

- `(?<![\w.-])` Negative lookbehind, assert not a word character, `.` or `-` directly to the left
- `-?\d+` Match an optional `-` and 1+ digits
- `[lL]?` Optionally match `l` or `L`
- `\b` A word boundary
- `(?!\.)` Negative lookahead, assert not a dot to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Tu722R/1)

**Edit**

To not match `1e-7` but do match the 7 in `e-7` you could add another negative lookbehind to the pattern that you gave in the comments:

```
(?<!\b\d+e-)(?<![a-zA-Z.])-?\d+[lL]?\b(?!\.)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1CqoKY/1)

You could also match what you want to get out of the way, and capture in a group what you want to keep:

```
\b\d+e-\d|(?<![a-zA-Z.])(-?\d+[lL]?\b)(?!\.)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zjtfyp/1)

****Edited by Cheny

I did a little change to deal with "    m_ned_1=1.2e+37 * 13e-7;     "

```
(?<!\b\d+[eE][-+])(?<![_a-zA-Z.\d])-?\d+[lL]?\b(?!\.)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pGoOUf/1)

****End

Comment: Thanks for your help! Just one more step https://regex101.com/r/yQ1rRi/1. I Just notice that the whole word 1e-7 is a science, while 7 alone in e-7 is an int. I'm confused that whether regex can do it.

Comment: @cheny It depends on the regex flavour. If a quantifier in the lookbehind is supported you can use for example another negative lookbehind https://regex101.com/r/Nqifcx/1 or add it as another alternative https://regex101.com/r/Oozpcr/1 Or you can match what you don't want, and capture what you want to keep https://regex101.com/r/Zjtfyp/1

Answer (score 1):

It's usually better to use a negative assertion when defining what's
not allowed. This is because it will mostly match BOS and EOS.
And that's really all the boundary's need to worry.

The stuff not allowed should be specific in a class, and try not to mix predefined
classes that cover many types like `\w` at least initially until you know all cases needed.

```
((?<![\da-zA-Z.-])(-?\d+[lL]?)(?![\da-zA-Z.-]))
```

https://regex101.com/r/dMvxBD/1

```
 (                             # (1 start)
    (?<! [\da-zA-Z.-] )
    ( -? \d+ [lL]? )              # (2)
    (?! [\da-zA-Z.-] )
 )                             # (1 end)
```

---

Update:

Based on new comment by cheny:
`1e-7 is a science, while 7 alone in e-7 is an int (as well as 12 in k-12)`

It gets more complex then. So this is trying to determine if the number
is not decimal, exponent or part of a variable name.

---

This will match a `+ or -` optional prefix where both are included in the output.

```
((?:(?<!\d[eE])[+-]|(?<![\da-zA-Z.+-])-?)\d+[lL]?(?![\da-zA-Z.]))
```

https://regex101.com/r/WGD1Bc/1

---

This will match a `+ or -` optional prefix, where only the minus is included in the match.

```
((?:(?<=(?<!\d[eE])([+]))|(?<=(?<!\d[eE])(?=(-)))|(?<![\da-zA-Z.+-]))-?\d+[lL]?(?![\da-zA-Z.]))
```

https://regex101.com/r/qVl2hL/1

These regex are identical in what they match. Only the output differ.

**** Edited by Cheny

I added a "_" in the middle to deal with "1" in ned_1.

```
((?:(?<!\d[eE])[+-]|(?<![_\da-zA-Z.+-])-?)\d+[lL]?(?![\da-zA-Z.]))
```

(https://regex101.com/r/0BF1l9/1)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Just two more steps https://regex101.com/r/yQ1rRi/1. I Just notice that the whole word 1e-7 is a science, while 7 alone in e-7 is an int (as well as 12 in k-12). I'm confused that whether regex can do it.

Comment: @cheny posted an update. Suggest using language parser if any more complexity is needed.

Comment: Yes, it's getting more and more tricky now. In fact I tried to identify all kind of numbers (float&double, int&long, hex, science...) in one regex. Now it's better to make them 4.

Comment: @cheny I recommend  a language parser because there are more complications you will run into.